# Need Help to trigger the helpKey F1 JavaHelp based on selected tree node (Eclipse-Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, treenode, javahelp

I need help on JavaHelp. The context-sensitive help offers, window-level, field-level (as in passing the component).

But i need to activate the JavaHelp when user press the HelpKey F1 or JavaHelp button from the tree node (the application built-in : Eclipse). 
Since the tree node is not a component, so it cannot directly call the enableHelpKey or enableHelpOnButton. Furthermore, i need to open the selected JavaHelp content based on selected tree node (example there 3 node courseware : Science, Math, English)

Really appreciate for ideas and help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The tree nodes are not JComponents but they are hosted in a JTree or other JComponent (JPanel). I would try to add a selection listener to the JTree and adjust the help topic for the JTree or JPanel.